# (ExtJS 4.x) Mask not showing in IE 8

Tags: extjs, extjs4, masking

I have a wait massage that is being shown to cover the page until the call is done with database and it doesn't work in IE 8, though it works for FF, the code I am using is

```
panel.body.mask('Loading. Please wait...', 'x-mask-loading');
```

and when it finishes the call i make it dissapear by

```
panel.body.unmask();
```

this works in FF however in IE it doesn't do any effects, but the forms are submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, one google search away, first hit.

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?89107-doesnt-display-masking-panel-in-IE8

Comment: I find it hard to believe that it isn't possible, Sencha provides some pretty good browser support. I am guessing you're correctly applying the mask before you make the call, and then unmask in the callback for the call?